# Get Random Node from Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

My method is suppose to return a random node from a BST, however it is not working correctly and I am unsure of why. The method is suppose to traverse the tree using preorder traversal while incrementing the counter. Once the counter is equal to the randomly generated number, it is suppose to return the node.

```
    // get random node
public Node getRandomNode(Node root) {

    // get random value between 0 to size of BST
    Random ran = new Random();
    int ranNum = ran.nextInt(size + 1);
    Node temp = root;
    System.out.println("random number is: " + ranNum);

    root = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp);
    return root;
}

int count = 0;

public Node getRandomNode(int ranNum, Node temp) {

    // traverse through the tree and increment count until count is the
    // random number,
    // in which case return the node it is on
    if (temp != null && count != ranNum) {
        count++;
        temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);
        System.out.println(temp.data);
        temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right);

    }
    // if count is equal to the randomly generated number
    return temp;
}
```

EDIT:
Using BFS

```
public Node getRandomNode(int ranNum, int count, Node temp) {

    if(temp == null)
        return null;

    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.add(temp);
    count++;    

    while(!q.isEmpty() && count != ranNum) {

        Node n = q.remove();
        System.out.println(" " + n.data);

        if(count == ranNum) {
            System.out.println("final node: " + n.data);
            return n;
        }

        if(n.left != null) {
            q.add(n.left);
            count++;
        }
        if(n.right != null) {
            q.add(n.right);
            count++;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your recursive calls.  Assume the random number is 1, you would expect the returned result to be the first node reached from the left subtree.  Your code will say `temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);`, and at this point the temp variable holds the correct answer, then you say `temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right);`, and at this point your temp variable holds an incorrect answer.

EDIT:
I decided to try to quickly fix your BFS implementation (quick = untested).  Note that I'm trying to keep my code as close to yours as I can, so I'm avoiding making any changes to your algorithm.

```
public Node getRandomNode(Node temp, int ranNum) {

    if(temp == null)
        return null;

    Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
    q.add(temp);
    int count = 0;

    while(!q.isEmpty() && count <= ranNum) {

        Node current = q.remove();
        System.out.println(" " + result.data);

        if(count == ranNum) {
            System.out.println("final node: " + n.data);
            return n;
        }

        if(n.left != null) {
            q.add(n.left);
        }
        if(n.right != null) {
            q.add(n.right);
        }
        count++
    }

    return null;
}
```

EDIT2:
Decided to fix your other version as well (still trying to stick very close to your original design).

```
    // get random node
public Node getRandomNode(Node root) {

    // get random value between 0 to size of BST
    Random ran = new Random();
    int ranNum = ran.nextInt(size + 1);
    System.out.println("random number is: " + ranNum);

    return getRandomNode(ranNum, root);
}

int count = 0;

public Node getRandomNode(int ranNum, Node node) {

    // traverse through the tree and increment count until count is the
    // random number,
    // in which case return the node it is on
    if (node == null || count == ranNum) {
        return node;
    }
    count++;
    temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);
    if (temp != null) {
        return temp;
    }
    return getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right);
}
```

Comment: How would you suggest I traverse the left and then right nodes? I was thinking of using 'getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);" instead of 'temp = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left);' (same thing with the right) to traverse through the tree, but then I wouldn't know how to save return the location that the pointer is at.

Comment: The problem is, assuming you have to use pre-order traversal, you need something from your return value that tells you that you're done.  Possible fixes are to use a wrapper around node or modify the node class (overkill), check your global count variable between invocations (doable, but I don't like globals), or to return null if the count variable wasn't reached (some people don't like returning null to signify things).  I'm assuming this is for an assignment so I'm trying not to just give you an answer.

Comment: Ok I'll try your suggestions and give you an update later. And nope I'm just doing problems from Cracking the Coding Interview since it's summer and I have the time! The book has a different solution, but this is the first solution I thought of so I'd like to continue with it.

Comment: I made some change and decided to use BFS instead (I added the edits above). The problem is that I still can't increment count whenever a recursive call is made such as q.add(n.left).

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is not totally random because you are retrieving the random node based on a count (randomly picked) but not randomly traversed!
the tree should return null if and only if the tree is empty.
because you have generated the random based on the size of the tree.

the Tree has two paths either right or left ...going either way should be random too ! **And should be thru one of them per method call(unless the the branch has been exhausted )**.
I changed the count variable from field to a method parameter 'cause it seems to be a temp and has nothing to do with class 
thus you don't have to reset the count each use of the class as well it is a good practice.
* another concern that you check for null what if the one of the side has a less 
number than the other that would make the the function exits because the node is 
null if this occurred on the left side traverse it the right would replace the temp but what if it happened on the other way it may return null !
by the way consider this as pseudo code I have never tested it :)

```
public Node getRandomNode(Node root) {
 Random ran = new Random();
 int ranNum = ran.nextInt(size + 1);
 Node temp = root;
 System.out.println("random number is: " + ranNum);

 root = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp,0);
 return root;
}



public Node getRandomNode(int ranNum, Node temp, int count ) {

    // traverse through the tree and increment count until count is the
    // random number,
    // in which case return the node it is on
    if (temp != null && count != ranNum) {
        count++;
      Random pathRan = new Random();
      int pathNo= pathRan.nextInt(2);
      Node temp2 = null;
      if(pathNo == 0){//if 0 go to left
        temp2 = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left,count);
        if(temp2 == null){//this means that this path has nodes less than count ,so try the right.
           temp2 = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right,count);
        }


      }else{//go to right
        temp2 = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.right,count);
         if(temp2 == null){//this means that this path has nodes less than count ,so try the left.
           temp2 = getRandomNode(ranNum, temp.left,count);
        }
      }
       return  temp2;
    }
    // if count is equal to the randomly generated number
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: That's a clever solution. I am still trying to fix my program even though it isn't necessary correct just because I would like to know what I am doing wrong. I'll implement your solution after that though! By the way, I decided to use BFS instead of preorder because I thought it might get rid of the problem I was having (turns out its not though). Any ideas? I added in the new changes.